# ATmega - reading PIN defined as PORT

Tags: atmega, pins, port

What value reads the ATmega328 in case:

```
DDRA = 0xff;
PORTA = 0x00;
pin_state = PINA;
```

another words, what is state of PIN if I/O is defined as output PORT and all PORT bits are set to LOW?

Comment: The PIN register reads from the port pins - see the datasheet for the gpio block diagram. Assuming all pins are set for output, then PIN should reflect the value of PORT, but if the hardware connected to a given gpio pin forces the voltage level, then the PIN value will reflect that. Eg if the gpio pin is set as an output and PORT sets it high but the circuit on that pin holds it low, PIN will read low rather than high. Put another way, reading PIN gives you the actual logic level of the pin, whereas reading PORT gives you what you last wrote to PORT.

Comment: @Kartman - Hi, Thanks for trying to help but [comments shouldn't be used to answer a question](/help/privileges/comment), so it is eligible for deletion. Please consider posting it as an answer instead :) Thanks.

Comment: @Kartman Thanks, nicely explained.

Comment: I wasn’t in a position to create an answer with the block diagram as Jasen did, so was just a comment.

Answer (score 1):

If the port is defined as output PIN will still read the logic value on the pin. if the pin is shorted the result may be different to the PORT value.

Here's how [the datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/Atmel-2486-8-bit-AVR-microcontroller-ATmega8_L_datasheet.pdf) explains it:
[image]

Furthemore pins that have a function other than GPIO enabled (eg PWM or USART) reading PIN will get the actual state of the pin but writing PORT will have no effect as the alternate function is in control of the pin.